# Java code snippet to shorten package name from fully qualified class name

Tags: java

How to get short fully qualified class name efficiently. For example if we pass "com.test.Student" we need to get "c.t.Student".

Comment: There are some snippets on code golf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119126/shorten-the-java-package#119137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NameAbbreviator](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/NameAbbreviator.html) from log4j-core.

```java
NameAbbreviator n = NameAbbreviator.getAbbreviator("1.");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
n.abbreviate("com.test.Student", sb);
System.out.println(sb); /* Result: c.t.Student */
```